# Usage of "also have...finally have" in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, isar

I usually think of `also have` as working like this:

```
have "P r Q1" by simp
also have "... r Q2" by simp
also have "... r Q3" by simp
...
also have "... r Qn" by simp
finally have "P r Qn+1" by simp
```

where `"... r Qm"` means `"Qm-1 r Qm"` and `r` is some transitive relation.

With `r` meaning `=` this seems to really be the case, however, when using `≥` I have found a counterexample to this description:

```
...
have  "1- 1/(2^(n+1))≥1/(2::real)" by simp
also have "... ≥ 0" (* here when I check the 'output' it seems to be 
considering  "0 ≤ 1 - 1 / 2 ^ (n + 1)" which in the previous notation 
would be Qn r Qn+2 !*)
```

My question is, how does `also have` work, in particular, how do I predict what `...` is going to refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIR, `a ≥ b` is an abbreviation for `b ≤ a`. With this in mind, you see that this does not fit the pattern expected by `also`.

I suggest that you state your chain of inequations the other way, from lowest to highest. You can still state the final result using `≥` if you want – after all, it is just an abbreviation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.       `have "0 ≤ 1/(2::real)" by simp
                                                      also have  "…≤1- 1/(2^(n+1))" by simp
                                                      finally have "0 ≤ 1- 1/(2^(n+1))"`

Comment: ... is what I changed it to, but what rule could I use to prove the last step? `simp` does not seem to work.

Comment: Oh, it's because I forgot to put `(0::real)`.